# Socket.io emit not called

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to emit two things from disconnection, and one is a redirect.

Server side:

```
 socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id]);
    socket.emit('redirect', destination);
    console.log('disconnect: '+ users[socket.id]);
    delete users[socket.id];
  });
```

Client side:

This gets called greatly:

```
socket.on('user-disconnected', username => {
    appendMessage(username+ ' est parti.');
    removeUser(username);
});
```

This does not:

```
socket.on('redirect', function(destination) { // never gets called…
    window.location.href = destination;
});
```

Do you know why my server-side gets called, user-disconnected does, but not my redirect ?

Thank you so much if you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending:

```
socket.emit('redirect', destination);
```

to a socket that has just disconnected.  You're literally trying to send the message from the `disconnect` event.  That socket isn't able to send more messages.  You can do `socket.broadcast.emit(...)` to send to all the other sockets, but not to this one.

Comment: Oh okay, so I cannot redirect my client that has disconnected ?

Comment: @Julien - `socket.broadcast.emit()` sends to all the other sockets EXCEPT the one that just disconnected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel stupid now, trying to emit to a disconnected socket. Yes I know that, I just wanted to redirect that person that got disconnected. I will do it by another way, from the client directly.  People get disconnected on my chat passed a certain time inactive, and I wanted to fix some issues related to that.